# Multi-level Authorization

Tags: authorization, saml, user-roles, xacml, abac

I need to implement authorization for some publicly hosted APIs. An external entity shall be allowed to consume an API after authentication and authorization. 
Basic auth will be used to perform authentication. 
Authorization shall be role based and has to be done at multiple levels:

1. If the identified user has a system_user role, allow API access else
2. If the identified user has not got system_user role, find out the account to which device (from which user is trying to access) is mapped in the database. Once the account has been identified, find out if that account belongs to the user and user has got the correct role for this account.

One way of implementing this logic is that I create everything proprietary using databases and code. But before I do that I want to know if there are some tools out there which can help in implementing this logic via some rules like XACML